# Raspberry Pi 3 - Access hostname in LXDE autostart

Tags: lxde, lxsession

I would like to pass the hostname of a Raspberry Pi to Chromium in ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

The relevant parts of the command are:

```
@chromium-browser --incognito --kiosk https://www.example.com?pi=`hostname`
```

I tried using several different syntaxes to either execute `hostname` or read the `$HOSTNAME` environment variable, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession

> Notice that lines are split on space characters, but no form of
>   escaping or quoting is supported, nor are multi-line commands. So if
>   you need, e.g., a command with a space in one of its arguments, put it
>   in a shell script and invoke the shell script from the autostart file.

Switched to call a shell script which invoked the browser.